# Why DO WHILE and DO UNTIL in SAS execute the loop body one more time after the loop should be stopped?

Tags: sas

**Question 1:**
For the DO WHILE, I wrote down the following code:

```
data do_while;
a = 0;
do while (a<1);
    a = a+0.1;
    output;
end;
run;
```

SAS gave me this:
[result of do_while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7ut.png)

I don't understand why 1.1 is outputted. Shouldn't the loop stop when a = 1?

**Question 2:**
For the DO UNTIL, I wrote down the following:

```
data do_until;
b=0;
do until (b>=1);
    b=b+0.1;
    output;
end;
run;
```

SAS gave me this:[result of do_until](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XetWI.png)

I understand that DO WHILE loop check condition before executing the loop body whereas DO UNTIL loop executes the loop body and then check the condition.

At some point when b=0.9, and SAS executes b=b+0.1(now b=1) and output it. Then SAS check the condition b>=1 is true so the loop should stop. But why 1.1 is still outputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that the `do while` condition is evaluated upon entry to the loop, and `do until` is evaluated at the end of the loop.

The issue is likely down to numeric representation of real numbers.

Internally, when incrementing by 0.1 ten times, you may end up with a value marginally less than 1 (e.g. 0.999999999989).

Change your condition to

`do while (round(a,0.1) < 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The output statement is in the wrong place.

```
data do_while;
   a = 0;
   do while (a<1);
      output;
      a = a+0.1;
      end;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't spot that!